# How to build multi oop functions in PHP5

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I have a question about OOP in PHP5. I have seen more and more code written like this:

```
$object->function()->first(array('str','str','str'))->second(array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

But I don't know how to create this method. I hope somebody can help me here, :0) thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key to chaining methods like that within your own classes is to return an object (almost always `$this`), which then gets used as the object for the next method call.

Like so:

```
class example
{
    public function a_function()
    {
         return $this;
    }

    public function first($some_array)
    {
         // do some stuff with $some_array, then...
         return $this;
    }
    public function second($some_other_array)
    {
         // do some stuff
         return $this;
    }
}

$obj = new example();
$obj->a_function()->first(array('str', 'str', 'str'))->second(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Note, it's possible to return an object other than `$this`, and the chaining stuff above is really just a shorter way to say `$a = $obj->first(...); $b = $a->second(...);`, minus the ugliness of setting variables you'll never use again after the call.

Comment: Just FYI: This technique is used to create a Fluent Interface (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Hmmm not more? and will all stuff be handle normaly? :)

Comment: @NeoNmaN: Depends on what you're trying to do, of course.  If your intent is to call a bunch of methods on a single object, then yes, this is how it's done.  Like i said, though, it's possible to return something besides `$this`.  If you do so, and especially if what you're returning isn't the same type or is totally unrelated to `$this`, that's a whole other thing than this -- and it's just shorthand for that last bit of grey code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object->function()->first(array('str','str','str'))->secound(array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

This isn't strictly valid PHP, but what this is saying is... You are calling a method on the $object class that itself returns an object in which you are calling a method called `first()` which also returns an object in which you are calling a method called `second()`.

So, this isn't necessarily just one class (although it could be) with one method, this is a whole series of *possibly different* classes.

Something like:

```
class AnotherClass {
    public function AnotherClassMethod() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public function MyClassMethod() {
        return new AnotherClass();
    }
}

$object = new MyClass();
echo $object->MyClassMethod()->AnotherClassMethod();  // Hello World
```