# How to make this in php?

Tags: php, method-chaining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build multi oop functions in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298707/how-to-build-multi-oop-functions-in-php5)

Hey,

I've seen this kind of code in a couple of forum systems but I can't find any examples like this:

```
$this->function()->anotherfunction();
```

You can see a similar example in PDO:

```
$pdo->query($sqlQuery)->fetch();
```

I don't know how this type of coding is called in PHP and thus I can't get on looking for any tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called method chaining. An example would be the following. Notice we are returning the current object.

```
class Example
{
   function test1($var)
   {
      return $this;
   }
   function test2($var)
   {
      return $this;
   }
}

$obj = new Example();
$obj->test1('Var')->test2(543)->test1(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this valuable information :)

Answer (score 3):

You just make sure a chainable method returns an object reference, and you can chain another method call onto the result.

You can `return $this` as @Tim Cooper shows, or you can return a reference to another different object:

```
class Hand
{
  protected $numFingers = 5;
  public function countFingers() { return $this->numFingers; }
}

class Arm
{
  protected $hand;
  public function getHand() { return $this->hand; }
}

$n = $body->getLeftArm()    // returns object of type Arm
          ->getHand()       // returns object of type Hand 
          ->countFingers(); // returns integer
```

The PDO example you show uses two different object types.  [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instantiates and returns a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, which in turn has a [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method.

This technique can also be used for a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP), particularly when implementing an interface for domain-specific language.  Not all method chains are fluent interfaces, though.

See what Martin Fowler [wrote about fluent interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) in 2005.  He cites Eric Evans of [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) fame as having come up with the idea.

Comment: ...and being a programmer, having your fingers protected is important for your livelihood ;)

Comment: This explains pretty much everything I had to know. Thank you :)