# Using $this->db->like() in Codeigniter returns wrong/missing results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an existing SQL query that works perfectly as I want it:

```
$this->db->select('places.*, category.*')
            ->select('COUNT(places_reviews.place_id) AS num_reviews')
            ->select('(places_popularity.rating_1 + 2*places_popularity.rating_2 + 3*places_popularity.rating_3 + 4*places_popularity.rating_4 + 5*places_popularity.rating_5)/(places_popularity.rating_1 + places_popularity.rating_2 + places_popularity.rating_3 + places_popularity.rating_4 + places_popularity.rating_5) AS average_rating')
            ->from('places')
            ->join('category', 'places.category_id = category.category_id')
            ->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->join('places_popularity', 'places_popularity.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->where('places.category_id', $category_id)
            ->group_by('places.id')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

However now I want to add a LIKE clause to the query by adding one more line to the above to get:

```
$this->db->select('places.*, category.*')
            ->select('COUNT(places_reviews.place_id) AS num_reviews')
            ->select('(places_popularity.rating_1 + 2*places_popularity.rating_2 + 3*places_popularity.rating_3 + 4*places_popularity.rating_4 + 5*places_popularity.rating_5)/(places_popularity.rating_1 + places_popularity.rating_2 + places_popularity.rating_3 + places_popularity.rating_4 + places_popularity.rating_5) AS average_rating')
            ->from('places')
            ->join('category', 'places.category_id = category.category_id')
            ->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->join('places_popularity', 'places_popularity.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->where('places.category_id', $category_id)
                            ->like('places.name', $term)
            ->group_by('places.id')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

However it is giving me inaccurate results. For example, when i let the string being searched $term = "hong" and I have 3 rows where the 'name' column matches "hong" ie. (Hong Kong Cafe, Hong Kong Cafe, Ramen Hong), I will only get (Hong Kong Cafe, Hong Kong Cafe) returned. Now if $term = "hong kong", I only get one of the 'Hong Kong Cafe' returned and not both.

Another one puzzles me even further! There is a row called 'Dozo'. When $term = 'dozo', no result is returned!

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Actual SQL generated**
Sorry it appears in 1 line

```
SELECT `places`.*, `category`.*, COUNT(places_reviews.place_id) AS num_reviews, (places_popularity.rating_1 + 2*places_popularity.rating_2 + 3*places_popularity.rating_3 + 4*places_popularity.rating_4 + 5*places_popularity.rating_5)/(places_popularity.rating_1 + places_popularity.rating_2 + places_popularity.rating_3 + places_popularity.rating_4 + places_popularity.rating_5) AS average_rating FROM (`places`) JOIN `category` ON `places`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id` LEFT JOIN `places_reviews` ON `places_reviews`.`place_id` = `places`.`id` LEFT JOIN `places_popularity` ON `places_popularity`.`place_id` = `places`.`id` WHERE `places`.`category_id` = 1 AND `places`.`name` LIKE '%Dozo%' GROUP BY `places`.`id` ORDER BY `average_rating` desc LIMIT 1, 3
```

**UPDATE**

SOLVED. Its a pagination problem that passes the wrong variable to the LIMIT clause. Thanks!

Comment: two years with CodeIgniter and I somehow didn't know you can append -> commands to previous ones.. I keep doing $this->db->... for each additional case.. +1 because i apparently suck ;)

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL that's being generated?

Comment: Posted the actual SQL at the bottom of the main post

Comment: @Atticus: That is not Codeigniter, that is simply php. By returning  the object in a method, you can chain methods. [Related Reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: well yeah, now im curious if CI does

Comment: Are you sure that `places.category_id = 1` is true for the fields you're querying? Nothing immediately jumps out at me otherwise.

Comment: @Atticus: curious if CI does what?

Comment: @Wesley -- curious if CI's database methods return the object back

Comment: @Atticus: Regarding [ActiveRecord](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/d07b76bf0e75/system/database/DB_active_rec.php), many of the methods do this, as you can see in OP's code. Not "all" of course, like returning results. Just query builder functions.

Comment: @Atticus: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#chaining

Comment: places.category_id = 1 is true for all. Every single row in the table has places.category_id = 1 at the moment

Comment: What happens if you run that exact query in MySQL Query Browser, PHPMyAdmin, or something similar?

Comment: @s992: I get the same result/problem when running the query above in phpmyadmin

Comment: UPDATE: I removed the LIMIT clause and it works!! What went wrong? And I need to use the LIMIT clause for pagination :(

Comment: UPDATE: SOLVED. SQL query is fine. Its a problem with passing the wrong variable to LIMIT clause. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Ah, you already figured the answer yourself I suppose!

Comment: I completely overlooked the LIMIT clause. Glad you got this sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your actual query, your `offset` is beginning from `1` instead of `0` this way it'll ignore the first record (at offset `0`).

So for the case:

> Another one puzzles me even further!
>   There is a row called 'Dozo'. When
>   $term = 'dozo', no result is returned!

Nothing will be returned obviously.