# OOP: a->user->chk and a->pwd->chk in PHP? How can I define?

Tags: php, oop, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

I had a function for create user, like **cruser** inside class and set password like **setpw**.

I want to create a validate function to check the username and password and I want use it like this:

```
$a = new class abc();
$a->cruser->chk();
$a->setpw->chk();
```

Need 2 different function or same can do?
It's so elegant, how can I define this?

```
class abc {
    function cruser { }
    function setpw {}
    //??? - need to define here chk or to different class?
}
```

for PHP 5.2/5.3.

How can I achieve this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Your password/username checking should be done by a different class/service.

Comment: I believe `$a->foo->bar()` is known as method chaining, and can be achieved by returning `$this` from each chain-able method. I'm a little sketchy on the specifics however.

Comment: Ruchard H: No, I want create in SAME CLASS THIS. I show phpunit example for tests, but I want know how I can define this. It's possible it's 100%. Question is: how? :)

Comment: Ross: can you type a little example how you define chk() if you want check cruser value and setpw values, if I call $a->cruser->chk and $a->setpw->chk? How can I detect inside of chk what function calling this chk() ?

Comment: bazmegakapa: it's not duplication because I had exact example what need to solve. :) But thanks your help too! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called method chaining. Your methods need to return the instance of the object being called.

```
class abc {
    protected $_username;
    protected $_password;
    public function cruser($username)
    {
        // Run your CREATE USER code here...
        // e.g., $this->_username = $username;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setpw($password)
    {
        // Run your SET PASSWORD code here...
        // e.g., $this->_password = $password;
        return $this;
    }
    public function validate()
    {
        // Validate your user / password here by manipulating $this->_username and $this->_password
    }
}
```

To set a username and password and validate, you'd call like this:

```
$a = new abc;
$a->cruser('user')->setpw('pass')->validate();
```

Comment: don't answer to a duplicated.