# Calling a Method on a method

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

So I can remember seeing in some code examples somewhere calling of a method on a method like:

```
$classname->method1()->method2();
```

Can you please explain to me what we call this, and give an example scenario of its usage?
Also if you have a link to a tutorial or article on this would be helpful.

I'm new to Object Oriented PHP. And before you kill me for what might be a dumb question, understand that i don't know what to search for on Google, please help...

Comment: method chaining.. tutorial here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: You mean [like this](http://codepad.org/AusqEWlS)?

Comment: Hey sorry tim, i didnt know what to search for, thats why i post a question

Comment: Hey Joshua don't worry about it, it's hard to search for stuff when you don't know what it's called! Now the next guy that seraches for "Calling a Method on a method" will be eventually directed to the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [*method chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and it's simply the process of calling a method on the object returned by another method.

For example, `method1` here returns an instance of some class that defined a method called `method2`, and so that method can be invoked immediately if you don't need the reference itself that `method1` returned. It's essentially equivalent to this:

```
$temp = $object->method1();
$temp->method2();
```

It's particularly useful when you have several methods returning references to the instance they were called on. In this case, rather than writing this:

```
$object->method1();
$object->method2();
$object->method3();
```

you can write this:

```
$object->method1()->method2()->method3();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a mil for the explanation, already making use of this in my code.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Basically it's when a function or method, in this case `method1()`, returns an object and you call another method on this returned object.

A typical use of this is when a method returns the object itself. This can be useful because it makes calling lots of methods on the same object very simple. You can just type:

```
myobj.doSomething().doSomethingElse().jump();
```

One prominent example of this is the JavaScript library [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in which most methods return a jQuery object.

Comment: Hey Thanks you, already making use of this in my code. Though Using "->" and not ".", since its php