# Methods as objects - How / when

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

In a lot of APIs I've worked with, I've seen this sort of thing:

```
$object->method()->anotherMethod();
```

From the tutorials on OOP that I've read, this is how classes are written,

```
<?php
class myClass {
    public method() {
       // do something
    }
}
?>
```

When should this be used, and how can it be done? Apologies, but I am new to OOP.

Comment: the method isn't an object, it returns an object (usually the same object as the first one) and the second method is called on that object

Comment: Is it possible to make it return another object? eg In the APIs I've used, the methods in $object are different to those in $object->method(). EDIT: You could use 'return new class();'?

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=method+chaining

Comment: also https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method returns $this, you will be able to use the above style (`$object->method()->anotherMethod()`). This can be done only in cases where your method is not expected to return something else, e.g. a method named like `getSomething()` is expected to return `Something`, but if you have a method that has no relevant value to return, you can just return $this, allowing method call chains.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Method Call Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  There are no hard and fast rules about when you should use it, but the general rule I use is that method chaining makes sense when there are a series of object methods that are frequently called one after the other, such as initialization functions.