# How to define method chaining in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

I want to use functions combined, like:

```
select("SELECT * FROM users").where("user=l0 ").join(" . . . ");
```

How to define this in php?

Comment: I feel I should warn you that this kind of thing is a *lot* harder to write than it looks. The simple example you've given won't be hard to achieve, but also won't achieve much (you might just as well write the query as a string). If you want it to do anything clever, it will be a very big project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function select(){
     ....
     return new myType;
}

class myType {

     function where(){
         ...
         return $this;
     }

     function join(){
         ...
         return $this;
     }

}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/pyrIEW0t

Remember to use `->` instead of `.` in PHP.

This is an example of PHP function chaining.

Comment: @user1792423 you don't unless you are just concatting strings (which I do not think you want to do).

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a `string` and you concatenate the return values of multiple functions.

```
function select($input) {

//process $input

return $output;

}

function where($input) {

//process $input

return $output;

}
```

In your php you can call these functions and get the returning result concatenated.