# class within another class

Tags: php, class

I am new to PHP OOP and would like to try to nest several classes within another class, to latter call them like so:

```
$sql = new SQL();
$sql->Head()->Description($_SESSION['page']);
  //OR
$sql->Head()->Keywords($_SESSION['page'])
  //OR
$sql->Body()->Clients($_SESSION['client'])
  //ETC
$query = $sql->Run(); // equivalent to mysql_query("...");
```

As you can guess, I run into some problems and ended with this poor code:

```
<?php
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/#some_db_directory/database.php');
//This file contains $db['host'], $db['user'], etc...

class SQL {
    public $sql;

    public function __construct() {
        global $db;
    }

    public class Head() {

        public function Description($page) {
            return "SELECT * FROM `$db['database']`.`desciption` WHERE `page` = '$page'";
        }

        public function Keywords($page) {
            return "SELECT * FROM `$db['database']`.`keywords` WHERE `page` = '$page'";
        }
    }
}

$sql = new SQL();
echo $sql->Head()->Description('home'); //For testing
```

- Is it possible to nest classes in PHP?
- If so, how is it done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php-method-chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining).

Comment: I don't think you can nest-declare classes; And even if you can, a **class** is not a **class instance**, so your `$sql->Head` is still a _class_, and `$sql->Head()->Whatever` is invalid. `$sql=new SQL()` is how you **instanize** a `SQL` class.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called `Encapsulation`. Try google search on [PHP encapsulation](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=php%20encapsulation&oq=php%20encapsulation&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.184.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.COAdUpaa4Lo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=bbe32b721707a7e1&bpcl=38093640&biw=1366&bih=667) to learn more.

Here is a code example from http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4060,

```
<?php 

class App { 

     private static $_user; 

     public function User( ) { 
          if( $this->_user == null ) { 
               $this->_user = new User(); 
          } 
          return $this->_user; 
     } 

} 

class User { 

     private $_name; 

     public function __construct() { 
          $this->_name = "Joseph Crawford Jr."; 
     } 

     public function GetName() { 
          return $this->_name; 
     } 
} 

$app = new App(); 

echo $app->User()->GetName(); 
?>
```

Comment: I think what the OP means is PHP5 Method chaining, and adding `return $this;` at the end of each methods in class, would do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `database.php` is a database class. In that case you could do something like this.

#### head.php

```
Class Head{
    private $_db;
    private $_dbName;

    public function __construct($db, $dbName){
        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->_dbName = $dbName;
    }
    public function Description($page) {
       $results = $this->_db->query("SELECT `text` FROM `$this->_dbName`.`description` WHERE `page` = '$page'");
       return '<meta name="description" content="' . $results['text'] . '">';
    }

    public function Keywords($page) {
       $results = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `$this->_dbName`.`keywords` WHERE `page` = '$page'");
       $keywords = array();
       foreach($results as $result){
           array_push($keywords, $result['word']);
       }
       return '<meta name="keywords" content="' . implode(',', $keywords) . '">';
    }
}
```

#### sql.php

```
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/#some_db_directory/database.php');
// Require head class file
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/#some_db_directory/head.php');   

Class SQL{
    public $Head;

    public function __construct($dbName){
        global $db;
        $this->Head = new Head($db, $dbName);
    }
}
```

You would then pass the name of the database into the SQL class (which propogates through to the Head class).

```
// Require the sql class file
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/#some_db_directory/sql.php');
$sql = new SQL('mydatabase');
echo $sql->Head->Description('home');
```

Again note that your database class might not return results the way I'm using them here. You will have to modify this to work with your particular database class.

Comment: I got lost in `head.php` @line 10, with the use of `_db->query...`. My $db array only has connection info >_< (host, user, password) . Although I would not mind creating a database class

Comment: @Omar ah, I was assuming $db was a database class already connected... check http://phpclasses.org they have alot of user contributed classes or what I prefer is [idiorm/paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) a mysql ORM/AR.

Comment: My very first class file, was a database file. I wonder if I can modify it, to make it work with your example?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376356/how-to-create-improve-database-php-oop-class-with-all-full-functions/13376663#comment18266724_13376663

Comment: I wouldn't re-invent the wheel (except merely for educational purposes). A community developed ORM or Active Record implementation is tested and can save alot of time developing for more important things :P

Comment: Since I do not have a database class that would work with your example, what/how to modify your code?

Comment: instead of `$this->_db->query(`... would be `$this = mysql_query(..`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<?php
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/#some_db_directory/database.php');
//This file contains $db['host'], $db['user'], etc...

class SQL {
    public $sql;
    private $_head;

    public function __construct() {
        global $db;
        $_head = new HeadClass();
    }

    public function Head() {
        return $this->_head;
    }
}

class HeadClass { // Class cannot have a public access modifier

    public function Description($page) {
        return "SELECT * FROM `" . $db['database'] . "`.`desciption` WHERE page = $page";
    }

    public function Keywords($page) {
        return "SELECT * FROM `" . $db['database'] . "`.`keywords` WHERE page = $page";
    }
}

$sql = new SQL();
echo $sql->Head()->Description('home.html');
?>
```

I am moving the class declaration outside the class and creating an *instance* of the class with in `SQL`.  This is then made available via the `Head()` function.

Note: For body you will need to create a separate class and use a reference in the SQL class to it like I have done for head.

Comment: what do you mean by -ve? **This is the error:** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/81/10038181/html/_tmp/nested-class.php on line 23

Comment: Joys of copy paste code - your original had more than one error in it.  Have updated the answer with the correct code.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function Description() on a non-object on line 32