# Can explain this block Code to me PHP XML DOMDocument Syntax

Tags: php, xml, dom, loops, foreach

I am currently learning different ways to iterate through the xml document tags using the 
php DOMDocument object, I understand the `foreach` loop for iterating through the tags, but the  `$element->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue` is a bit unclear to me could somebody explain to me in detail? Thank you.

```
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load('StudentData.xml');

    $studentRoot = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Student');
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($studentRoot->length); $i++) {
        $firstNameTags = $studentRoot->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('FirstName');
        echo $firstNameTags->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue.' <br />';
    }

    /* so much easier and clear to understand! */
    foreach($studentRoot as $node) {

        /* For every <student> Tag as a separate node, 
           step into it's child node, and for each child,
           echo the text content inside */  

        foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
            echo $child->textContent.'<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$elements->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue
```

First:

```
$elements
```

The current elements<sup><sup>**$**</sup></sup> as parsed and referenced. In the code example, that would be:

```
$firstNameTags = $studentRoot->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('FirstName');
$firstNameTags->...
```

Next:

```
->item(0)
```

Get a reference to the first of the `$elements` [*item* in the node list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php). Since this is zero-indexed, `->item(0)` would get the first *node* in the *list* by *index*.

```
->childNodes
```

Get a list of the [child nodes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) to that first `$elements` node referenced by `->item(0)` above. As there is no `()`, this is a (read only) *property* of the `DOMNodeList`.

```
->item(0)
```

Again, get the first node in the list of child nodes by *index*.

```
->nodeValue
```

The [value of the node](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) itself.

---

If the form of the state alone:

```
$obj->method()->method()->prop
```

Confuses you, look into [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining), which is what this uses to put all of those method calls together.

---

<sub><sup>**$**</sup> Note, you left off the `s`, but that indicates there's one or more possible *by convention*. So `$element` would be *zero or one* element reference, `$elements` might be zero, one or more in a collection of `$element`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much now I don't have to ask my Prof, tomorrow!

Comment: @ErrolWallace - No problem. Please upvote if you can and mark as the answer if that is the case.