# Why can't I use an object when I construct it?

Tags: php, oop, syntax-error

I've tried searching for this but frankly I don't know what to search for and unfortunately I imagine this question has been asked before.

In PHP, and possibly other languages, why can't I use an object immediately after I create it?

```
// This causes an error
$obj = new Object()->myFunction();
```

Note: I return `$this` in most of my setter functions so I can chain them together

```
function myFunction() {
    // ... some more code here ...

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply invalid syntax in PHP.  You are able to get this to work in PHP 5.4 by wrapping the object constructor expression with parentheses:

```
$obj = (new Object())->myFunction();
```

See [PHP 5.4 new features](http://www.php.net/manual/migration54.new-features.php):

> - Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. `(new Foo)->bar()`.

If you want `$obj` to be the value of the new Object, be sure to return `$this` from `Object::myFunction()` (this is called [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)).

An alternative for getting constructor chaining to work is to have a static method in your class which creates the new class instance for you:

```
class Object {
    public function __construct($var) {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
    public static function newObject($var) {
        return new Object($var);
    }
}

$obj = Object::newObject()->chainMethodX()->chainMethodY()->...
```

Comment: worth noting here to that $obj will be populated with the return of myFunction... only will be the object if myFunction returns $this

Comment: Thanks @Orangepill I forgot to mention that in my question. I'll add it now

Comment: @Orangepill I wonder, how this weird syntax can be used. Constructors were invented for this.

Comment: @Tim Cooper is there a difference between `(new Foo)->bar()` and `(new Foo())->bar()`?

Comment: @chrislondon:  No.  In both cases, they call the constructor for the class.

Comment: The manual makes no mention of the precedence associated with `->` but it must be that it is higher then `new`.  The precedence order that is on the site puts new and clone on top.

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid syntax.

PHP only supports:

```
$obj = new Object();
$obj->myFunction();
```

Keep in mind that, were you code sample to work, `$obj` would  get the return value of `myFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks Fritz! My question is why doesn't PHP support new Object()->myFunction()?

Comment: And the answer is: because.

Comment: A lot of my setter functions `return $this;` so I can chain the functions together so `$obj` equaling the return of `myFunction()` is ok.

Comment: Cool :) fluent APIs are all the rage.

Answer (score 1):

Although not documented on the site it would appear as though the object operator `->` has a higher precedence then the new keyword. So saying:

```
$obj = new Object()->someFunction();
```

is evaluated like you wrote

```
$obj = new (Object()->someFunction());
```

instead of the intended

```
$obj = (new Object())->someFunction();
```

The real reason it works this way is in  [the php grammer definition](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#775) on line 775

Comment: You probably meant to link to [this line](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#775). Declaring the T_NEW token is hardly "the real reason it works this way".