# Is it possible to nest mysqli commands

Tags: php, mysqli

Using the php mysql functions, if I have a query that I know will only return one row from the data table I nest the functions like this:

```
$myVariable = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SOME QUERY"));
```

Using the mysqli functions I have to have to use two lines of code:

```
$query = $db->query("SOME QUERY");
$myVariable = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Is it possible to condense the two lines into one as I do using the older mysql functions?

Comment: Have you tried condensing them yourself?

Comment: You cloud simply use `mysqli_query` etc. (not beautiful but wokring). Maybe (not tested) you could use `$db->query("...")->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: @Jimbo yes, I had tried myself, but after a few variations that didn't work I thought I'd ask people who may have done it before.  I've only started looking into mysqli today.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as "not constructive". Seems a valid question to me. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
$myVariable = $db->query("SOME QUERY")->fetch_assoc();
```

It's a bad idea because you don't get the opportunity to do any error handling. For example:

```
$myVariable = array();

$result = $db->query("SOME QUERY");
if($result && $result->num_rows == 1)
{
    $myVariable = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

If you nest or chain the calls, you might run into unhandled fatal errors because `query()` will return false if there was a MySQL error.

If you're looking to tidy up your code or reduce it, you could extend the MySQLi class and add your own method to fetch a single row.

Comment: Thanks, chaining was what I was looking for, as also mentioned by @Le_Morri.

As I said, I use it when I know that there is only one record to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining) them:

`$myVariable = $db->query("SOME QUERY")->fetch_assoc();`

Although both that and your intial `mysql_` usage are prone to errors. Neither will handle a failed query particularly nicely.

Comment: this is wrong way of running queries

Answer (score -1):

As a matter of fact, you **should not have** to condense the two lines into one using older mysql functions, and shouldn't do it with new ones.

When *a programmer* needs to condense something, they write *a function*. So you have to.

So, what it have to be

```
$myVariable = my_function("SOME QUERY");
```

As you can see,

- it is shorter and more readable than all these nested/chained/entangled constructs
- it has error handling, profiling logging and many more
- if you were using a function already, you won't even had to rewrite your existing code.