# Method Chaining and Class Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, method-chaining

I think I have more or less managed to get a grasp on OOP/Inheritance, and the basics of method chaining I think I understood as well. However I am still confused about how to actually use some of it.

I wanted to do something that I've seen when working with Magento before:
In Magento, I've seen some sort of "selector-function" used in method chaining. It's a little hard to put into words, but it was something along the lines of:

```php
$categoryName = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getName();
```

It's the `load($categoryId)` part that interests me, as in, a function that selects some instance of something and allows me to run a function on that specific instance.

Now, I am writing a module that allows me to configure certain promotions on our website. Seeing as we'll have many different promotions and I want them to be easily configurable and modifiable, I wanted to do something similar.

So, if I wanted to be able to do something like this:

```php
$prm = new Promotion();

$prm->addPromo('xmasPromo');
$prm->addPromo('nyPromo');

$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->setName('Promotion for Xmas!');
$prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->setName('Promotion for New Years!');

echo $prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for Xmas!
echo $prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for New Years!
```

How would the class definition for that have to look like?

This may be much more simple or much more complicated than I anticipate. In either case, thanks a lot!

---

Edit:
So I did some testing around with the info deceze gave me, but I'm still confused.
Bad naming and putting 2 classes in 1 file aside, here's what I did:

class file:

```
class Promotion {
    private $__arr = array();
    public function addPromo($name) {
        $this->__arr[$name] = new Promo();
    }
    public function getPromo($name) {
        $this->__arr[$name];
    }
}

class Promo {
    private $name;
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

and the run file:

```
require_once 'class.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$prm = new Promotion();

$prm->addPromo('xmasPromo');
$prm->addPromo('nyPromo');

$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->setName('Promotion for Xmas!');
$prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->setName('Promotion for New Years!');

echo 'X: '.$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for Xmas!
echo "\n";
echo 'N: '.$prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for New Years!
```

This gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in /var/www/test/index.php on line 11`.
But why? Shouldn't getPromo() give me back the object?
Thanks again..

---

Thanks to the great guys here, it works now. In case anyone were to pass by here with the same or a similar question, here's the final, working code:

Classes:

```
class Promotion {
    private $__arr = array();
    public function addPromo($name) {
        $this->__arr[$name] = new Promo();
    }
    public function getPromo($name) {
        return $this->__arr[$name];
    }
}

class Promo {
    private $name;
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
require_once 'class.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$prm = new Promotion();

$prm->addPromo('xmasPromo');
$prm->addPromo('nyPromo');

$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->setName('Promotion for Xmas!');
$prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->setName('Promotion for New Years!');

echo 'X: '.$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for Xmas!
echo "\n";
echo 'N: '.$prm->getPromo('nyPromo')->getName(); // returns: Promotion for New Years!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: That's called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) - so method will return self instance. In some sense it's an anti-pattern

Comment: Actually the issue I can see is, you should be returning the `PROMO` instance from the `getPromo` method like `return $this->__arr[$name];`

Comment: deceze beat you to it by a minute or two. You're absolutely right of course, I was just too blind to see that I forgot it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method chaining is really simple, all it does is use one particular element of PHP's syntax:

When a function returns an object, you can directly continue with `->` after that function.

The longhand version can be:

```
$bar = $foo->bar();
$baz = $bar->baz();
echo $baz;
```

`$foo->bar()` returns an object (`$bar`) which has a method `baz()`, and that method returns some value (`$baz`). This can be written in shorthand like so:

```
echo $foo->bar()->baz();
```

`$foo->bar()` still returns an object which has a method `baz()`, so you can directly call it without assigning it to an intermediate variable. Maybe this makes it more obvious:

```
echo ( $foo->bar() )->baz();
```

You're calling the `baz()` method on whatever `$foo->bar()` returns.

```
$prm->getPromo('xmasPromo')->setName('Promotion for Xmas!');
```

As such, in your above case, all you need to do is to return an object which has the method `setName` from `getPromo`. I would assume `getPromo` is supposed to return some object of, say, the `Promo` class. If the `Promo` class has a method `setName`, you're all set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Having the "Promotion" class and "Promo" class (which has setName and getName methods) is easy. But how do I make the addPromo and getPromo functions in the "Promotion" class create or respectively getriebe the appropriate instance of the Promo object?

Comment: I don't know, that's up to you. When you call `addPromo`, the `Promotion` class creates a new `Promo` object (not good naming BTW) and stores it somewhere internally with the given name. When you call `getPromo`, it retrieves that object. Could be as simple as an array, or could be as complex as a database query. It's your decision what you actually want to do here.

Comment: I appreciate our help. I tried it with arrays, but I still can't seem to get the hang of it. See original post.

Comment: Maybe because you're not `return`ing the value?!

Comment: Aw jeez. How could I have been so blind. Also forgot to `$this` in getName. Works now. This answers my question, and I really helped me understanding the concept. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chain methods you just need to always return the object like this

```
class Chain {
    public function firstChain() {
         //do something
         return $this;
    }

    public function secondChain() {
          //do some stuff

          return $this;
    }

}
```

Than when you have an instance of the class you do like this:

```
$obj = new Chain();

$obj->fistChain()->secondChain();
```