# use muliple method in one object in php

Tags: php, class, object, method-chaining

I am new to php and crating classes for my project . I have reached this far  ..

```
$db->select('id');
             $db->from('name');
             $db->where("idnum<:num");
             $db->bindparamers(':num',100);
             $rows=$db->executeQuery();
```

I wana know to create methods such that i can use all thing at once like below

```
$db->select('id')->from('name')->where('idnum>100')->executeQuery();
```

I have tried searching but not getting what exactly i should search for

here is my class structure

```
class Dbconnections
{
    //For Complex Queries
    public function select($items)
    {

    }
    public  function from($tablenames)
    {

    }
    public function where($arr)
    {

    }
    public function orderby($order)
    {

    }
    public function bindparamers($parameter,$value)
    {

    }
    public function executeQuery()
    {}


}
```

What changes i need to make to use it as :

```
$db->select('id')->from('name')->where('idnum>100')->executeQuery();
```

Comment: You just need to `return $this` in all your methods

Comment: method chaining is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called *method chaining* and in your case can be achieved by returning `$this` from each method.

```
class Dbconnections 
{
    public function select($items)
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public  function from($tablenames)
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public function where($arr)
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public function orderby($order)
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public function bindparamers($parameter,$value)
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
    public function executeQuery()
    {
        // ...
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called *fluent interface* ;)

Comment: @Jefffrey your solutiong works perfertly fine . But now that is i dont want to create all methods as my chaining methods like : i want only 2 methods to be chained for select()  ex. `$db->select()->from()->where()` and if i am doing update then `$db->update()->set()->where()`  like wise i only need to make where as my global chaing and from and set will be dependent on select and update is that possible ?

Comment: @VikramSangat, you should open another question for that.