# PHP references with "new" operator

Tags: php

PHP documentation [states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

> Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically

Any examples to illustrate this statement?

Comment: Link you shared have some examples.

Comment: Actually, the most important use case is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
class reftest
{
    public $a = 1;
}

$reference = new reftest();
$reference2 = $reference;
$reference->a = 2;

echo $reference->a;  // echoes 2.
echo $reference2->a; // echoes 2.
```

Note that both `$reference` and `$reference2` have the value of the member `$a` equal to 2, despite the value was only assigned to the `$reference`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = new ClassA();
$b = $a;
```

Variables `$a` and `$b` are pointing to the same place, where `ClassA` resource exists.