# Concept of code piping in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose if you wanted to call few methods from another object. What is the proper way of doing it.

And if you use `__call()`, is it possible to extract the arguments, instead of using it as array.

Example:

```
<?php

class Component
{
    protected $borrowMethods = array();

    public function __call( $name, $args )
    {
        if( isset( $this->borrowMethods[$name] ) )
        {
            $obj = $this->borrowMethods[$name] ;
            return $obj->$name( $this->argExtractFunc($args) );
        }

        throw new \Exception( 'method not exists' );
    }
}

class ActiveRecord extends Component
{
    protected $validator; //instance of validator 

    protected $borrowMethods = array(

        'validate' => 'validator',
        'getError' => 'validator',
        'moreMethods' => 'someOtherClass',
    );

    public function save()
    {
        if($this->validate())
        {

        }
    }
}

class Validator
{

    public function validate(){}

    public function getError( $field ){}

}

$ar = new ActiveRecord;

$ar->getError( $field );
```

Comment: Can you put pseudo code of what you trying to do?

Comment: In `__call`, the 2nd parameter contains an array of the arguments.  What does "extract the arguments" mean?  Why can't you use the array?

Comment: I am aware of chaining,

Comment: Are you looking for `return call_user_func_array(array($obj, $name), $args);`?

Comment: Yeah right Hazmat, thats what i was looking for. I dont know how i missed it. thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely undestand what you're asking, but I believe what you're referring to is known as [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Each of your methods needs to return `$this` (or another object), which the original caller can then immediately call another method on.

```
class Test
{
    public function one() {
        echo 'one';
        return $this;
    }

    public function two() {
        echo 'two';
        return $this;
    }

}

$test = new Test();
$test->one()->two();  // <-- This is what I think you're trying to do
```

**Update**

In regards to your update, I don't think that is good design practice.  How much maintenance would the `$borrowMethods` array require?  How much more tightly bound is your `ActiveRecord` implementation to your `Validator`?  Instead, why not just implement your own `getError` method within `ActiveRecord` that returns the results of calling `$validator->getError($field)` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called **method chaining**. See this SO topic: [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

The arguments in `__call()` can be obtained through: `func_get_args()`