# Why calling function from the name returned from another function does not work in PHP?

Tags: php

I am just amazed that why below code does not work

```
function test(){
  echo "this is test";
}

function getName($f)
{
  return $f;
}

getName("test")();
```

It works when I put function name in variable like this

```
$f = getName("test");
$f();
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2):

that's not possible to call a multiple functions directly, you must have to store return values to other function and then try to call other function.

Instead, if you want to access multiple functions at a same time just call other function in the first function. See below code for your reference

```
 function test() {
      echo "this is test";
    }

    function getName($f) {
        $a = $f();
        return $a;
    }
    getName("test");
```

Comment: That actually not entirely true anymore... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining gives examples.