# What is this PHP syntax?

Tags: php, syntax, frameworks

I recently saw some sample PHP code that looked like this:

```
$myObj->propertyOne = 'Foo'
      ->propertyTwo = 'Bar'
      ->MethodA('blah');
```

As opposed to:

```
$myObj->propertyOne = 'Foo';
$myObj->propertyTwo = 'Bar';
$myObj->MethodA('blah');
```

Is this from a particular framework or a particular version of PHP because I have never seen it work?

Comment: Are you sure? That has syntax errors; you mean it without the `;` and with paranthesis? as in _method chaining_

Comment: Zend Framework does handle that. But than leave the semicolan after foo and bar

Comment: Are you sure about that syntax? I guess you saw a method chaining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Comment: @Daan - does ZF handle it for directly setting properties like that? Or does it only do so via setters?

Comment: @MarkBaker directly you don't need a setter for it.

Comment: @Daan - I'm intrigued now, trying to figure out how `$myObj->propertyOne = 'Foo'` could actually return an object instance, unless they're using magic __set()

Comment: @MarkBaker Not sure how ZF did manage that. I'm sure you can find it in the documentation http://www.zendframework.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you saw was `fluent interface`, however your code sample is wrong. To make long story short, `fluent setter` should return `$this`:

```
class TestClass {
    private $something;
    private $somethingElse;

    public function setSomething($sth) {
        $this->something = $sth;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setSomethingElse($sth) {
        $this->somethingElse = $sth;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$sth = new TestClass();
$sth->setSomething(1)
    ->setSomethingElse(2);
```

Comment: That's really nice :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe that it would actually work as you've shown it with the semi-colons after each line, nor for assigning properties directly; you may well have seen something like

```
$myObj->setPropertyOne('Foo')
      ->setPropertyTwo('Bar')
      ->MethodA('blah');
```

which is commonly called a `fluent interface` or `method chaining`, where each of the methods returns the instance of the current object via `return $this`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at Method Chaining which I'd never heard of in PHP before.  Obviously my example is nonsense.

This post makes sense of it for me:

[PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)