# Call to a member function InnerJoin() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, class

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to create a database class with inner join functionality but I'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function InnerJoin() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\world\index.php on line 10

My code:

```
<?php 

class DB {
private static $_link = null,
               $_host = "127.0.0.1",
               $_pass = "",
               $_dbname = "mundo",
               $_user = "root",
               $_charset = "utf8";
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_count = 0,
        $_error = false,
        $_results;

private function __construct() {
    $this->_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$_host.";dbname=".self::$_dbname,self::$_user,self::$_pass);
}

public static function getLink() {
    if(!isset(self::$_link)) {
        self::$_link = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_link;
}

public function Get($table) {
    return $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
}

public function Go() {
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        echo "prepared";
    }
}

public function InnerJoin($table1, $column1, $table2, $column2){
    return $this->_query = $this->_query." INNER JOIN ".$table2." ON ".$table1.".".$column1." = ".$table2.".".$column2;
}
}
?>
```

and in my index.php i have this:

```
<?php 
$DB = DB::getLink()->Get("paises")->InnerJoin("paises","Id_Continente","Continentes","Id_Continente")->Go();
?>
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're returning `$this->_query` from `Get` function where as it requires to return a complete object to use it again,

```
public function Get($table) {
    $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
    return $this;
}
```

For more detail read *[**Method Chaining**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)*.

Comment: He's returning a boolean, not _query

Comment: i just needed to return $this instead of $this->_query, i already update the question with the solution

Comment: You can't update the answer in question. If this answer helps you just  [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it so that it helps future users.

Comment: I have rollback to your original question. Nothing to update now. Enjoy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

```
$DB = DB::getLink()->Get("paises")->InnerJoin("paises","Id_Continente","Continentes","Id_Continente")->Go()
```

you have here 3 method calls in one instruction... there is no problem with this when each function returns the object that has to call the next function.

But this is not happening here.

`getLink()` initialices the object DB and retunrns it, so next its ok:

```
DB->Get("paises")
```

this returns a boolean telling if the assignment `$this->_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;` succeeded... and here is when you fail:

```
1->InnerJoin
```

try not doing all at once, examining the return and constructing the next step accordingly.

Comment: i just needed to return $this instead of $this->_query, i already update the question with the solution