# multiple T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in php

Tags: php

I'm a beginner and having trouble understanding the -> syntax in php, i know that it is used to access object in a class, but what does it mean if i you put multiple ->, for example:

```
$this -> $var1 -> var2 -> var3
```

Comment: That's called [method chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: @John It's not method chaining if there's no method. :)

Comment: In your case, your class contains a variable $var1 which itself contains a variable $var2 which also contains a variable $var3

Comment: oh sorry, complete newbie here. thanks guys :))

Comment: @deceze Would you call it property chaining? Well it's not really chaining anyways more like traversing through an object.

Comment: @Dave I'd call it "breaking the Law of Demeter". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as accessing nested arrays using this:

```
$arr['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

(I hope this analogy is helpful to you.)

```
$this->var1->var2->var3
```

Here `$this` is an object which has a property `var1`. `var1` is also an object itself which has a property `var2`. `var2` is also an object itself which has a property `var3`. It could be constructed as such:

```
$this->var1 = new stdClass;
$this->var1->var2 = new stdClass;
$this->var1->var2->var3 = new stdClass;
```

Comment: You may often use this in decoding JSON as well, [such as this](https://eval.in/private/2fff72e45e63d4).