# Listed arrow notations in php?

Tags: php

This is something that I have been really curious about. I have tried to find the answer myself but I can't exactly think what to google. So first off, I am used to doing a regular query method either like this (when escaping):

`$Database->query($sql)`

or if using prepared statements like this:

`$Database->statement($sql, array('ss', $val1, $val2))`

However when reading through the source code of a project, I found this:

```
$id = DB::SQL()
                ->select("postId")
                ->from("post")
                ->where("conversationId=:conversationId")->bind(":conversationId", $conversation["conversationId"])
                ->orderBy("time DESC")
                ->limit(1)
                ->exec()
                ->result();
```

Now I know this is PDO, and also a random example however since I read this I've been wondering how this is done. If someone would be kind enough to explain then I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you asking how "method chaining" is implemented?  Simple, have each method return the same object it was called with.  If it's part of a class, then `return $this;`.

Comment: this is what i call method chaining ..;)

Comment: PDO in PHP does not support method chaining, nor does the given example look like PHP's PDO interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have done here is `method chaining`.

A simple example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining).

```
<?php

class fakeString

{
private $str;
function __construct()
{
    $this->str = "";
}

function addA()
{
    $this->str .= "a";
    return $this;
}

function addB()
{
    $this->str .= "b";
    return $this;
}

function getStr()
{
    return $this->str;
}
}


$a = new fakeString();

echo $a->addA()->addB()->getStr(); //outputs ab
```