# Using more than 1 function in-line from class

Tags: php, function, class, object, optimization

How can i use a more than 1 function inline from object?
I have simple class:

```
class test
{
    private $string;

    function text($text)
    {
        $this->string = $text;
    }

    function add($text)
    {
        $this->string .= ' ' . $text;
    }
}
```

so how i can use this class as:

```
$class = new test();
$class->text('test')->add('test_add_1')->add('test_add_2');
```

not like:

```
$class = new test();
$class->text('test')
$class->add('test_add_1')
$class->add('test_add_2')
```

And at end in class $string will be: `test test_add_1 test_add_2`

Comment: I believe you have to `return $this` at the end of the function

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return `$this` so you can then continue work on the object:

```
class test
{
    private $string;

    function text($text)
    {
        $this->string = $text;
        return $this;
    }

    function add($text)
    {
        $this->string .= ' ' . $text;
        return $this;
    }
}
```