# call two functions with one this keyword in php

Tags: php, this

How does this work:

```
$a = $this->A()->B();
```

In php? Can i get an example to understand this? Or any docs or sources to understand this. Which of the function will be called first and why?

And is method chaining possible only for methods in same class?

Answer (score 1):

Below code first call function `A` after that call function `B`.

```
$a = $this->A()->B();
```

It is known as PHP Method chaining.

Also you can take reference  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining).

Comment: One more question is method chaining possible only if all the methods are in same class?