# Methods inside Methods PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, object

The following code is the sample code:

```
$sample= $module->get('data')
            ->anotherModule
            ->find(true);
```

I couldn't understand what exactly is the object hierarchy in here. According to my knowledge, there must be an object `$module` and that class has a method `get` which takes the parameter as `'data'`.

But according to the code, still it gets deeper to `anotherModule` and `find` method. Can anyone explain me what is happening in this code?

Comment: its call chaining... you can do this if all method will return some object ex. self [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **method chaining**.

A method returns an object which contains other methods. You can find an example for that here: [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)