# Using $this when not in object context without the use of static methods

Tags: php, class, oop, object, static-methods

I'm trying to manually decrypt my owncloud's files to test it, but I don't know the PHP language well.

The problem I'm facing is:

> PHP Fatal Error: Using $this when not in object context

I looked around for some time, but all I came across was using `$this` wrongly along with static methods. But, there aren't any static methods in the files I'm editing.

There's a file `'script.php'` where I'm calling another file's `(crypt.php)` methods.

script.php:

```
<?php 
namespace OCA\Files_Encryption\Crypto;
use OCA\Files_Encryption\Crypto\Crypt;
require_once 'crypt.php';

.
.
.

$decryptedUserKey = Crypt::decryptPrivateKey($encryptedUserKey, $userPassword);

.
.
.
```

Here's the other crypt.php file, where the fatal error occurs
crypt.php

```
<?php
namespace OCA\Files_Encryption\Crypto;

class Crypt {

.
.
.

public function decryptedPrivateKey($privateKey, $password = '', $uid = '') {
    $header = $this->parseHeader($privateKey);
.
.
.
}

}
```

The last line of code throws the fatal error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use **`$this`** in static call. Because **$this** is refer **current object** and you haven't created any object for class Crypt.

Also you haven't declared **decryptedPrivateKey** method as **static.**

You can call class method by two ways. You can use [*Tom Wright's*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610232/4198099) suggested way

**(1) Call with object**

```
$crypt = new Crypt(); // create class object
$decryptedUserKey = $crypt->decryptPrivateKey($encryptedUserKey, $userPassword); // call class method via object
```

OR

**(2) Call without object (static call)**

**a)** You should define method as static.

**b)** You should use [self keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this) and call another static method,

```
public static function decryptedPrivateKey($privateKey, $password = '', $uid = '') {
    $header = self::parseHeader($privateKey);
}

public static function parseHeader() { // static parseHeader
  // stuff
}
```

**In above case, parseHeader method must be static as well.**

So you have two options:-

**i)** Either declare  parseHeader method also static OR

**ii)** **create object of current class and call non static method parseHeader**

```
public static function decryptedPrivateKey($privateKey, $password = '', $uid = '') {
     $obj = new self(); // create object of current class
     $header = $obj->parseHeader($privateKey); // call method via object
}

public function parseHeader() { // Non static parseHeader
  // stuff
}
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have a better idea now.
What about for calls like $this->abc->def(); ?

Comment: You are welcome :-) It is object chaining. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Comment: Thanks again!
What I meant was, how should I modify such method chaining calls?
I tried using the same method as you mentioned by declaring the methods as static and doing this: self::abc->def() but that did not work.

Comment: You can use self  and call self::abc()->def() only if you will create class object in abc() method and return $this. then only it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks again @Ravi Hirani

Answer (score 3):

You may not have defined `decryptPrivateKey` as `static`, but that is how you are using it.

It is then going forward and using `$this` when it isn't actually part of an instantiated object.

Try using this in script.php

```
$crypt = new Crypt();
$decryptedUserKey = $crypt->decryptPrivateKey($encryptedUserKey, $userPassword);
```