# Php "sub methods"?

Tags: php, class

So I've been using an API this days to interact with discord, there's a method that called my attention:

`$guild = $discord->guilds->get('id', 'guild id');`

As you can see, there's the class $discord and a method (or sub-method) called guilds->get();

I've been looking onto the code of the api but I can't find anything related to how the "sub-method" `get();` is implemented inside the `guild->`

Can someone help me with this? I think that system is pretty awesome for organizing code.

Pd: I don't certainly know how to explain that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Comment: `guilds` is a property, not a method