# Check if call is method chaining PHP

Tags: php, method-chaining

I want to know about method chaining. Recently I have used method chaining in Laravel, it's working fine.

My Model name was Posts so when I want to select all names from posts it returns all names.

> Posts::select('name');

And when I call below function to get one records it gives only one record.

> Posts::select(name)->first();

I want to implement same scenario in my own class. I have a class of image uploading.

If I will upload only a file, it will be

> Image::upload('pic')

But If I upload image with resize and watermark.

> Image::upload('pic')->resize(200, 300)->addwatermark('image/logo.png');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: The question is not same! first read then comment and vote. Thanks!

Comment: There's not even a question in your post. I see "I want to implement same scenario in my own class.", how to do that is answered in the link I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your methods must do : "return $this;" once treatment is done :

```
public function upload(){
    //do something

    return $this;
}

public function resize(){
    //do something

    return $this;
}

public function watermark(){
    //do something

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what if i have to only upload file and return the filename then I can't return object of the class.

Comment: You can do your whole treatment chaining methods, then call a getFileName method once you are done.

Comment: But in laravel we didn't need to call any function for getting file name. I already think about it and whole logic is in my mind. But the issue is how framework manages this.