# Call multiple methods on object?

Tags: php

I tried calling multiple functions on a single object. But I think I failed the syntax. Could you correct me please?

```
    $objMetaDaten->setStrTitle('test')
        ->setStrBeschreibung('test')
        ->setStrUeberschrift('test')
        ->setStrCanonical('test')
        ->setStrRobots(MetaDaten::INDEX);
```

Comment: for this to work, each method must return `$this`. Look **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)** , method chaining.

Comment: show your error  message

Comment: If `setStrTitle('test')` returns the next class, I mean `(setStrBeschreibung('test'))`'s object then this will be occur.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need is something called fluent setters which will return the object after calling a setter on the object as against the conventional void setters something like below

```
Class A{
   private $name;
   private $id;

   public function setName($name) {
        $this–>name = $name;
         return $this;
    } 

    public function getName() {
     return $this–>name;
     } 

     public function setId($id) {
        $this–>id = $id;
         return $this;
     } 

     public function getId() {
         return $this–>id;
     } 
}
```

So you can then say

```
 $test = new A();

 $test->setId(1)->setName('Fredrick');
```