# Oneliner to call multiple functions with the same argument in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have 2 or more functions that always takes the same arguments. The argument is the returned value of another function call.

**This is the code:**

```
$result = getMyResult();

myFunction1($result);
myFunction2($result);
...
```

**Question**

Is there a way to call multiple functions on the same line with the same argument?

*An example of what I'm trying to achieve:*

```
myFunction1,myFunction2...(getMyResult());
```

*Demands*

- The solution can be procedural or object oriented.
- I don't want to temporary store the returned value of `getMyResult()` in a variable.
- I only want to call `getMyResult()` once.
- I don't want to wrap the function calls in a helper function *

* like this.

```
function myHelperFunction($result) {
    myFunction1($result);
    myFunction2($result);
    ...
}
```

*If `myHelperFunction()` is the closest solution, then I'm happy to hear about it.*

Comment: Answer is the last line of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some more research and the closest I´ve been able to come to an answer that lives up to my requirements is with 1: an **object oriented approach** and **fluent setters** or 2: with a **helper function**.

(Found Solution 1 here: [Call multiple methods on object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069983/call-multiple-methods-on-object))

**Solution 1** *(3/4 requirements)* Make a class with methods and have every method return the object itself.

```
$result = getMyResult();
$myclass->myMethod1($result)->myMethod2($result)->...
```

The only "problem" is that I have to store the argument in a temp variable because I don't want to call `getMyResult()` more than once.

**Solution 2** *(3/4 requirements)* Helper function procedural solution.

```
function myHelperFunction($result) {
    myFunction1($result);
    myFunction2($result);
    ...
}

myHelperFunction(getMyResult());
```

The only "problem" is that I have to define a function that calls all my other functions. This function is not dynamic because I can not control the number of functions called inside without implemententing further logic.

**Conclusion**

I can't find any solution that meets all my reqiurements and I can't determine if there is another solution out there at this point. Both **Solution 1** and **2** would make designing my code easier. For now I will settle with **Solution 1**.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that this is still hanging around without a really satisfactory answer. Here is a function that will call any number of functions with the same argument.

It's a pretty common pattern.

It's not a one liner, but once you write it, you never need to again (no need for a helper function each time). Prior to PHP 7.4, it looks like this:

```
function for_effect() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  return function() use($args) {
          $inner_args = func_get_args();
          array_walk($args, function($fn) use ($inner_args){call_user_func_array($fn, $inner_args);});
  };
}
 
$print_me = function() {
  var_dump( func_get_args());
};

for_effect($print_me, $print_me)('Some argument');
```

Post 7.4, it's a bit nicer:

```
function for_effect() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return function() use($args) {
        $inner_args = func_get_args();
        array_walk($args, fn($fn)=>call_user_func_array($fn, $inner_args));
    };
}
```