# How to call a class function from a instance call?

Tags: php, oop

So I currently have a class and wanted to make class calls cleaner by being able to call the class instance as a function, like the `__toString` magic method which outputs a string when called, instead be able to call `$instance()` as a function and have it called.

Like:

```
class MyClass {
  public function __onCall() {
    echo 'This was called when the user called the instance!';
  }    
}

$instance = new MyClass();
$instance();
//opts: This was called when the user called the instance!
```

Essentially I want to be able to chain class functions and cut off one chain that'll be called a lot by calling a function from the instance.

Syntax I want:

```
$Class('Some String')->SomeFunction()->AnotherFunction();
```

Syntax I have:

```
$Class->select_string('Some String')->SomeFunction()->AnotherFunction();
```

:-)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you really need to have a structure like this when in fact you are dealing with OOP.

Comment: @Aldee This isn't the exact way it's being used,  it's meant to do a call like: `$string('TestString')->AnotherCall()->MoreCalls()`, since that's easier syntax than `$string->select_string('TestString')->AnotherCall->MoreCalls()` if that makes sense, so that's the reason I wanted to use this method. `:-)`

Comment: Please check my answer below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I see what you mean here. So you want to have a fluent method chaining. This is actually [answered by another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724136/969645)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aha yeah I know how to chain methods, I just want to cut one chain off by being able to call a function that'll be called a lot directly from the instance of the class, I'll add that to my question. :~)

Comment: Ahh. okay, I see. I suppose this might be of interest for you http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php - but this is for PHP 7 only I guess.

Comment: Ahah I found it, didn't think to look at the magic methods, `__invoke`! http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke