# How to chain method with Model current state?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-5.3

I have a model where I get total of order like this:

```
public function total()
{
    $total = $this->subtotal();
    foreach ($this->lineItems as $l) {
        $total += $l->amount;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

I want to add method `formated()` which will format `subtotal` and `total` method returns with function `number_format($numberHere, 2)`.

I want it to be dynamic not like: `totalFormated` or `subtotalFormated`. I want to output formated value like this: `$order->total()->formated();`.

Is there any chance I can get that to work?

Comment: Nothing is impossible but I would recommend against it. You'll need to bloat your Model with a lot of additional logic for these methods that have nothing to do with database. Maybe look at [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for these types of "computed attributes". However if you really want to make it chainable [here's a good start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: I don't want to add `number_format($numberHere, 2)` every line I want to output total or subtotal or discount or tax amounts. That's why I want to implement that here. Or if you suggest any other(better) solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create total as an instance variance

```
protected $total;
```

then change your function to this

```
public function total()
{
    $this->total = $this->subtotal();
    foreach ($this->lineItems as $l) {
      $this->total += $l->amount;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

then create the formated function

```
public function formated()
{
  return number_format($this->total, 2)
}
```

now you can chain the function like

```
$order->total()->formated()
```

** **Updated** **

you can return both total and subtotal in formated function

```
public function formated()
{
  return [
      "total" => number_format($this->total, 2), 
      "subtotal" => number_format($this->subtotal, 2)
   ];
}
```

** **or** **

you can use one instance variable for both total and or subtotal. let name this varibles myTotals

```
protected $myTotals;

public function total()
{
    $this->myTotals = $this->subtotal();
    foreach ($this->lineItems as $l) {
      $this->myTotals += $l->amount;
    }

    return $this;
}


public function subTotal()
{
    $this->myTotals = $this->subtotal();
    foreach ($this->lineItems as $l) {
      $this->myTotals += $l->amount;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function formated()
{
    return number_format($this->myTotals, 2)
}
```

so in this case you can call

```
$order->total()->formated() // and this will return the total
$order->subTotal()->formated() // and this will return the subtotal
```

Comment: It only will work with total. I want it to work with subtotal too. Thank you.

Comment: @Buglinjo have you tried applying this same principle but inside `subtotal` method as well?

Comment: i dnt really understand how u want to to work with subtotal. But will update my answer on possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save your `$total` as a property (`$this->total += $l->amount`) and at the end of your `total()` method return the current instance of your class = **$this**, basically:

```
public function total()
{
    $this->total = $this->subtotal();
    foreach ($this->lineItems as $l) {
        $this->total += $l->amount;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Now your method returns the instance of the *Class* itself so you can call the other method (or anything else within that class):

```
public function format()
{
    return number_format($this->total, 2);
}
```

And with this you should be able to "chain" your methods. The key is to return the **instance**.

`$order->total()->formated()`