# How i can make a selectable object in any Php class?

Tags: php, class, oop

When i use the some php frameworks or libraries i can write code like this:

```
$avariable = new aClass();
$avariable->someFunction()->somevalue
```

(I want to create  structure like this.)

I try create  a class name Customer

```
class Customer {
  public function getCustomer($name,$email,$age){
    ...
    $customer = new \stdClass();
    $customer->description = 'Description';

    return $customer;
  }
}
```

And then try

`$customer= new Customer();
$customer->getCustomer('name','email','age')->description ;`

Why my code is not work

> $customer->getCustomer('name','email','age')->description;

thanks

Comment: Looks like you want to do [method chaining, mayhaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: What do you mean by not work? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: *... my code is not work* is not a good description of your problem. Please explain the *expected* Vs. *current* output.

Comment: Just testing what you have there seems to work. I get the output `Description`...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if 'description' is a method that returns a value within the Customer class  It should work.

```
class Customer {
   public function getCustomer($name,$email,$age){
    ...
       $customer = new \stdClass();
       $customer->description = 'Description';

       return $customer;
   }
   function description()
   {
       return $something;
   }
}
$customer= new Customer();
$customer->getCustomer('name','email','age')->description() ;
```