# use a function after a function PHP OOP

Tags: php, application-pool, method-chaining

i have a simple question in OOP

I've see in a lot of frameworks like Laravel something like this :

```
$data = Model::OrderBy('id','desc')->skip(5)->take(10)->get()->toArray();
```

My Question is, how can i can call a function after another function ?

Exemple :

```
class test{

public function test1(){}
public function test2(){}

}
```

how i can call the function test 2 after test 1 like that `test1()->test2()`

i hope the question is clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724136/2411636 <- take a look at this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In its simplest form you just have to return the current instance in all your chainable methods:

```
return this;
```

Often these chained methods return a new object instead of altering the current one though - this is called immutability or immutable objects.