# how we can set many setters on class php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this result on my php code, I need the implementation of

```
class person 

    $person = new person();

    $person->setFirstName('name')
        ->setLastName('lastname')
        ->setEmail('email@example.com')
    ;

    echo $user;
```

and then i have this result
  Will result a string

"name Lastname "

IS the example of my class implementation but it didn't work I need to implement three setters setFirstName,setLastName,setEmail to get my result code above .

```
class User {
  private $FirstName;
  private $LastName;
  private $Email;
    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->FirstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName($x) {
        $this->FirstName = $x;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->LastName;
    }

    public function setLastName($x) {
        $this->LastName = $x;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    public function setEmail($x ) {
        $this->Email = $x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$user` come from and where is what you have tried? Perhaps the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) will help you understand how to do this.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining to learn about method chaining (hint: create the functions in the class that will return `$this`), then you can also create a get function to get one or all of the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand. Anyways this code will provide you a class Person and test it.
Output: "name lastname <email@example.com>"

Code:

```
    class Person
    {
        private $firstname, $lastname, $email;

        function setFirstName($firstname) {
            $this->firstname = $firstname;
            return $this;
        }

        function setLastName($lastname) {
            $this->lastname = $lastname;
            return $this;
        }

        function setEmail($email) {
            $this->email = $email;
            return $this;
        }

        function __toString() {
            return $this->firstname. ' ' .$this->lastname. ' &lt;' . $this->email .'&gt;';
        }
    }

    $person = new Person();

    $person->setFirstName('name')
        ->setLastName('lastname')
        ->setEmail('email@example.com');

    echo $person;
```

Hope this is what you searched for! I think what you need is the & gt; and & lt;

Comment: `public function __toString() {` and `echo $person;`

Comment: Thanks my friend is what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your answer correctly, you want the following:

```
echo $person->getFirstName() . ' ' . $person->getLastName() . ' ' . $person->getEmail();
```

**Resulting in:** Samir Guiderk Samir@example.com>

Comment: He wants you to write the code for him, ie `class Person { ... }` do not answer to off-topic questions.