# What logic is behind laravel serial functions?

Tags: php, laravel

Actually I am trying to know that how laravel is accepting multiple methods, suppose in laravel you can do something like below

```
Game::where('season_id', $timeSpanId)
->where('team_id', $whoId)
->where('stats_done', 'yes');
->get();
```

So in above script I can understand `Game` is a class and `where` can be a method. But in php we use method only once but in above script you can see in single line it can be use. And also look at `get()` method which is at the end of the script which would know that it need to fetch the record after execution of generated query.

Now suppose I have a class

```
Class Car{

    public function seat($param){
        return $param;
    }

    public function tyre($param){
        return $param;
    }

}
```

and I can use the methods as like below

```
$Car = new Car();
$Car->seat('Passenger Side');
$Car->tyre('Driver Side');
```

above script will return the result in proper way but I don't think that I can use as following

```
$Car->tyre('Driver Side')->seat('Passenger Side');
```

As far as I know that above script will throw an error, but that's I want to know that how laravel is doing that.

Can someone please give me idea of that logic of term that I can learn about it.

I am so sorry for question title, as I am not sure what it should be, you can help me by editing it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The keyword you want to go read up on is _method chaining_.

Comment: To be able to chain calls like this, you need to do `return $this;` instead of `return $param;`. It means that you obviously can't do this for functions that should return a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Comment: You need to learn first about method chaining in php. using chain you can return full method instead of value using return $this inside method.

Comment: It's the laravel [fluent query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#introduction), it's a way to construct a query with a "fluent" and expressive "language", almost all methods called return the instance of the query builder itself ($this) so you can chain methods.