# PHP Syntax, is $this->(stuff) ->(more stuff) the same as $this->(stuff); $this->(more stuff)?

Tags: php

just learning PHP and I have a project I'm looking at which appears to have typos but I'm not sure if they are or not.

I want to know if the output of the two bits of code below is the same.

```
  $this->addSubmitElement($this->_buttons[self::BTN_LIST], self::BTN_LIST);
  $this->addSubmitElement($this->_buttons[self::BTN_DRAFT], self::BTN_DRAFT);
```

and

```
  $this->addSubmitElement($this->_buttons[self::BTN_LIST], self::BTN_LIST)
   ->addSubmitElement($this->_buttons[self::BTN_DRAFT], self::BTN_DRAFT);
```

It seems it should be but my project behaves differently depending on which version I have.

Comment: If your project behaves differently then it's not the same. Second code is an example of method chaining: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: The first example returns two values (one for each line). The second example returns a single value (because the `addSubmitElement` method is _chained_). So they are not the same.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Comment: If the return value of `addSubmitElement()` is `$this`, then yes, they do the same

Comment: Thanks all, I understand better now. I felt Jeroen's answer was the most clear. I'll look into method chaining some more.

Answer (score 0):

There's a common pattern used when designing 'mutating' methods (setSmth, addSmth) that update some properties of an object: use that object (i.e., $this) as return value.

Following this pattern enables chaining you've showed in your second example. Note that this is a pattern, but not a requirement; if the package changed, you're not able to use that approach anymore.