# PHP add Class to another Class

Tags: php, class, object

I want to start a subscription with `start` and if `addTrail` in present alter the outcome of `start`.

**Start subscription without trial period**

```
 (new Premium)->start(1, 'paid', 30);
```

**Start subscription with 15 days of trial period**

```
 (new Premium)->start(1, 'paid', 30)->addTrial(15);
```

**To illustrate**

```
class Premium
{
    private $trialDays;

    public function start($user_id, $type, $endsInDays) {

        if($trialDays) {
            $endsInDays = $endsInDays + $trialDays;
        }

        return 'Your subscription will end in ' . $endsInDays . 'days';

    }

    public function addTrial($days) {
        $this->trialDays = $days;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Answer (score 1):

Your start function has to `return $this;` if you want to "chain" methods

```
public function start($user_id, $type, $endsInDays) {
    if($trialDays) {
        $endsInDays = $endsInDays + $trialDays;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Otherwise use standard syntax

```
$premium = new Premium;
$premium->start(1,'paid',30);
$premium->addTrial(15);
```