# PHP OOP structure

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to improve my OOP skill. Recently, I've read an article that has this code structure:

```
$this->getUserInfo()->display();
```

When I code, I just do something like this:

```
$this->getUserInfo();
```

How do I do something like the above..."multiple-passing" or whatever it's called. I think it's cool if I can make my code be able to do that...just looking at the code...I'm impressed.

Can somebody post a code something replicating the above...I want to try it too. I want to learn how^^

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298707/how-to-build-multi-oop-functions-in-php5

Comment: oh so the term is mutiple oop...a! Thanks Tim!

Comment: No, the term is "method chaining".

Comment: Also known as "fluent interface" (but that has multiple meanings, and "method chaining" is technically more correct).

Comment: Yep...it's much more easier to learn if you know what it's called in the first place. Google is just around the corner :D Thanks GUYS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to simply return an object from the `getUserInfo()` method, often the method returns the object it belongs to, i.e. `$this`.

```
function getUserInfo() {
    // do something
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want know more i suggest that know more about design pattern in OOP consept from [Design pattern in simple examples](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5127)